# Highlight ListView Item From Code - WPF Data Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

**Previous Sources I Visited (and did not find an answer):**

1. [Highlight Row In WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776470/how-to-highlight-selected-row-in-wpf-listview-control-with-alternating-backgroun)
2. [Selected Item Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838524/how-to-set-a-wpf-listview-selected-item-color)
3. [Highlighting Items In WPF ListView](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18585/Highlighting-Items-in-a-WPF-ListView)
4. [Triggers For Styling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-use-triggers-to-style-selected-items-in-a-listview)
5. [Styles For Styling](http://dotnetbutchering.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-set-wpf-listview-selected-item.html)

And more closely-related yet too complicated/not exactly what I need sources.

**General Information:**

As tagged, this code is in `c#`, using `WPF`, with target framework `.NET Framework 4.5`.

*Note:*
This is my first try at implementing `MVVM`, so **comments** about best-practices i'm missing will be appreciated (although this is **not** the main subject of this question).

**Question:**

WPF with a `ListView` and a `Button`. The `Button` removes items from the `ListView`.

> `ListView<String>` (View) ---> `RemoveStringFromList()` (ViewModel)

The above works. My problem is with **highlighting**.

I want to be able to remove a string from the ListView, and after removal ***highlight a different Item***.

My initial thought was that by using a Property (`SelectedItemProperty`) that binds with the `ListView`'s `SelectedItem` property - the highlighting will be **automatic**.

But in practice, the `SelectedItem` property binding works - as i can keep pressing the `Button` and remove items that became the `SelectedItem` per the logic implemented in the `SelectedItemProperty` setter - but although they are selected code-wise, **they are not highlighted.**

**Code:**

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="213.06">
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsProperty}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemProperty}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="214" Margin="35,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button Command="{Binding RemoveString}" Content="Remove From List!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" Height="46"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly MainWindowViewModel _viewModel;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
            DataContext = _viewModel;
            Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<String> _list;
        private String _selectedItem;

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            _list = new ObservableCollection<String> {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
            RemoveString = new RemoveStringCommand(this);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<String> ItemsProperty
        {
            get { return _list; }
        }

        public String SelectedItemProperty
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    _selectedItem = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (_list.Count > 0)
                    {
                        _selectedItem = _list[0];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public ICommand RemoveString
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public bool CanRemoveString
        {
            get { return _list.Count > 0; }
        }

        public void RemoveStringFromList()
        {
            if (SelectedItemProperty != null)
            {
                _list.Remove(SelectedItemProperty);
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }


    }
}
```

**RemoveStringCommand.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Input;
using WpfApplication1;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class RemoveStringCommand : ICommand
    {
        private MainWindowViewModel _viewModel;

        public RemoveStringCommand(MainWindowViewModel viewModel)
        {
            _viewModel = viewModel;
        }

        public event System.EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _viewModel.CanRemoveString;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _viewModel.RemoveStringFromList();
        }
    }
}
```

**App Image - Before First Click**

[image]

**App Image - After 1 Click (Notice - No Highlight!)**

[image]

**App Image - After 2 Clicks (Still No Highlight...)**

[image]

Comment: In addition to located below answer I suggest to learn something about markup controls `StackPanel`, `WrapPanel` and `Grid` features `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions`. Otherwise `Margin` would kill you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all remove a mistake

```csharp
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    DataContext = _viewModel;
    // Show(); remove this, it's not needed
}
```

I made an example with two reusable helper classes.

1) First common class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It may help not to repeat INPC implementing in each ViewModel class.

```csharp
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

`[CallerMemberName]` here allows not to include Property name to each `OnPropertyChanged()` call. Compiler will do it automatically.

2) Class for easy Commands use. (grabbed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic))

```csharp
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

3) In the following example i changed names for properties as you asked for suggestions. Don't name properties such as `SomethingProperty` to avoid conflicts with Depency Properties, this naming pattern would be useful with DP only.

Markup:

```xaml
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedItemIndex}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="214" Margin="35,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Button Command="{Binding RemoveItem}" Content="Remove From List!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" Height="46"/>
</Grid>
```

4) ViewModel:

```csharp
public class MainWindowViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _itemsList;
    private int _selectedItemIndex;
    private ICommand _removeItem;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        // never interact with fields outside of the property 'set' clause
        // use property name instead of back-end field
        ItemsList = new ObservableCollection<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> ItemsList
    {
        get => _itemsList;
        set
        {
            _itemsList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); // Notify UI that property was changed

            //other ways doing the same call
            // OnPropertyChanged("ItemsList");
            // OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemsList));
        }
    }

    public int SelectedItemIndex
    {
        get => _selectedItemIndex;
        set
        {
            _selectedItemIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // command will be initialized in "lazy" mode, at a first call.
    public ICommand RemoveItem => _removeItem ?? (_removeItem = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        ItemsList.RemoveAt(SelectedItemIndex);
    }, 
    // SelectedItemIndex -1 means nothing is selected
    parameter => SelectedItemIndex >=0 && ItemsList.Count > 0));
}
```

As a bonus you may programmatically change `SelectedIndex` of `ListView` simply setting any value to `SelectedItemIndex`.

**Edit:**

Sorry, I've forgot to keep selection after deletion. Modify the command:

```csharp
public ICommand RemoveItem => _removeItem ?? (_removeItem = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    int index = SelectedItemIndex;
    ItemsList.RemoveAt(index);
    if (ItemsList.Count > 0)
        SelectedItemIndex = (index == ItemsList.Count) ? index - 1 : index;
}, parameter => SelectedItemIndex >= 0 && ItemsList.Count > 0));
```